# We are trying to setup Firebase Phone Authentication in an application we are building using Bubble.io, however, we are unable to make it work

Tags: firebase-authentication, bubble.io

We have the custom code but we are not able to store the outputs of the code into bubble Database.
We are using the code in an HTML element in bubble.
The toolbox plugin which picks up javascript code into bubble workflows is not working in this case because we are importing firebase libraries.
Firebase libraries can’t be imported while running a workflow hence toolbox plugin doesn’t work. If the libraries can be imported, the workflow would succeessfuly initiate an OTP to authenticate the phone number.

We are stuck here and need help.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)